# Field name case sensitivity in mysql subqueries( version 5.6 vs version 8 )

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6, mysql-8.0

Upgrading from MySQL5.6 to MySQL8 is creating problem for field name case sensitivity in sub queries.

I've tried reading MySQL8 documentation and various articles related to case sensitivity, but could not find the solution.

```
SELECT  productId 
  FROM ( SELECT a.PRODUCTID 
           FROM ( SELECT ProdId ProductId 
                    FROM tblproductmaster 
                   ORDER BY CreatedDateTime DESC limit 10 ) a ) a ;
```

Expected output in both version 5.6 and version 8

```
+-----------------+
| productId       |
+-----------------+
| PROJTZ00734     |
| 75882M56R00B4   |
| 1161085S10-B200 |
| HRZ00136        |
| HRZ00135        |
| HRZ00134        |
| HRZ00133        |
| IMPOZ00148      |
| IMPOZ00147      |
| MAINZ01682      |
+-----------------+
```

But actual output in version 5.6 is

```
+-----------------+
| productId       |
+-----------------+
| PROJTZ00734     |
| 75882M56R00B4   |
| 1161085S10-B200 |
| HRZ00136        |
| HRZ00135        |
| HRZ00134        |
| HRZ00133        |
| IMPOZ00148      |
| IMPOZ00147      |
| MAINZ01682      |
+-----------------+
```

and in version 8 is

```
+---------------+
| PRODUCTID     |
+---------------+
| 46201M79G00B3 |
| 46201M59K00B2 |
| 59288M81R10   |
| 59238M81R00   |
| 59286M81R10   |
| 59236M81R00   |
| 59234M81R00   |
| MAINZ01482    |
| MAINZ01481    |
| CONZ00171     |
+---------------+
```

Comment: What do you mean by "field name sensitivity"? I do not think this is a problem here. Can you add the createddatetime-value to your query/output (e.g. `SELECT ProdId ProductId, CreatedDateTime ...` ) to verify which of those results is the correct one/if there is an error? While the order of the rows in your final result is undefined, the content should be identical, unless the time value is equal for some of those (e.g. all `null`), in which case MySQL is free to choose any row amongst those with the same creation time.

Comment: @NikhilKaushik . . . Most likely reason:  the data is different in the two databases.

Comment: @Solarflare, Actually the problem is not regarding data, please heed to the casing of column name, in MySql5.6 it is **productId** but in MySql8 it is **PRODUCTID**. The application is written in PHP with MySQL and an error of Undefined Index is being thrown wherever multi level sub query is written.

Comment: Ah, I missed the problem, I thought since the content of  the expected output differed from the actual output, that would be the problem. Columnnames in sql are case insensitive, so MySQL doesn't care which one it uses. The optimizer changed in MySQL 5.7, and it can just remove your outer select. You can use aliases to pick your own spelling though. I'll elaborate in an anwer.

Answer (score 0):

Column names are [case insensitive by definition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> Column, index, stored routine, and event names are not case sensitive on any platform, nor are column aliases.

MySQL is free to choose any version, but will pick the the latest version it comes across. Which is not necessarily the version you think.

What happens here is that the optimizer in MySQL 8 optimized the query by [merging the two outer layers into one](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html), while MySQL 5.6 didn't know this kind of optimization yet. The execution plan in MySQL 5.6. should look similar to

```
id  select_type table               type    possible_keys   ...         
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>          ALL                         
2   DERIVED     <derived3>          ALL                         
3   DERIVED     tblproductmaster    ALL
```

while for MySQL 5.7 and above, you should get a row less:

```
id  select_type table               type    possible_keys   ...         
1   PRIMARY     <derived3>          ALL                         
3   DERIVED     tblproductmaster    ALL
```

This is obviously a good idea, as it makes your query potentially run faster by having to do less work. Basically, MySQL simplified your query to something like

```
SELECT a.PRODUCTID from (SELECT ProdId ProductId FROM tblproductmaster 
               ORDER BY CreatedDateTime DESC limit 10 ) a
```

There is no specification that requires MySQL to either pick the outer or inner spelling in the merging process (and it might change in future versions). MySQL will however honor an alias, which is what you would need to use here if you need a specific case:

```
SELECT productId as productId FROM ( SELECT a.PRODUCTID from ( ... ) a ) a
```

should yield

```
+-----------------+
| productId       |
+-----------------+
| PROJTZ00734     |
```

Unfortunately, you will need to modify (all) your queries for this, there is no "always pick the outmost spelling case"-option, as for MySQL, the case is not relevant and was never specified, and it just by chance turned out that MySQL until now picked the case you prefered.

You can however disable this merging optimization altogether. While it could make some queries slower, it might work as a temporary solution to make your code work until you adepted it (which you should do eventually). To disable the `derived_merge` (and leave all other options with their defaults), you can use the [optimizer switch](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/switchable-optimizations.html)

```
set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';
```

Don't forget to add it to your configuration file, otherwise it won't survive a server restart. This should make your queries behave like MySQL 5.6 with regards to merging, and as a side effect, you should get the MySQL 5.6 spelling. Athough, as a disclaimer, the behaviour is still unspecified, so edge cases or future versions might still behave differently.